Hetzner/Rails: Why am I unable to connect to 443?
I have created a new Rails app and have using Kamal to push it to my new Hetzner server. I have no firewalls installed.
I have tested the app runs on port 80 with curl <ip>:80 which returns the expected source.
However, testing the same on port 443 (curl <ip>:443) returns:
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.

(Is this because I haven't provided a certificate?)
I get the same results when I SSH into the server and curl to the localhost.
I also get the same result when I try pointing my browser to <ip>:443
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.

It does however work when I point my browser to port 80.
Using watch -n1 docker container ls I can confirm the server is listening to port 443.
2acd4c170636   basecamp/kamal-proxy:v0.8.2                                "kamal-proxy run"        2 hours ago     Up 2 hours     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->
443/tcp   kamal-proxy

Why can't I connect to port 443? Why when I try do I get the message, 'Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server'. How do I fix it?

Have you tried curl  https://

No! Having tried that, I get: curl: (35) LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B438:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert internal error

check this out -- https://serverfault.com/questions/985689/error14004438ssl-routinesconnect-cr-srvr-hellotlsv1-alert-internal-error
